# Flutter faild host lookup error on real device

Tags: android, ajax, flutter, https, host

"I'm making HTTP requests in Flutter using the http library, and it works fine on the emulator. However, when I test the developed app on a real device, it shows a 'failed host lookup' error. I want to emphasize that it works perfectly on the Android emulator, but this error occurs on a real device. I've even tested it on Android 11, 12, and 13, and it works fine on the emulator. What could be the problem when running it on a real device?"

the source code is :

```
 String endPoint = "https://simple.com";
  //  get token from api
  Future getToken() async {
    Token token = Token();
    var uri = Uri.parse(endPoint+"/Login");
    var body = convert.jsonEncode(apiInfo);
    var response = await http.post(uri,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      token.token = jsonResponse["Data"]["UserToken"];
      Token.getToken=token;
    }
  }
```

i change
`Uri.https` to `Uri.parse`

and not work

Comment: Do you have an active internet connection on the real device? :D

Comment: yes , i have internet connection